# How to label INNER JOIN column result

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, calculated-columns

Here I am using an inner join to return the number of stations in each zone.

I get the result

```
Zone       (No column name)
MIDDLESEX       4
```

How to do I label the column above?

I tried to do **as 'No_of_Stations'** insde the inner join

Here is the code I have.

```
select 
dbo.FindIntersectingZone(location) as 'Zone',
count(*)
from 
londonStations
inner join [planning_districts_2008_updated] on [planning_districts_2008_updated] .geom.STIntersects(stations.location) = 1 
group by
dbo.FindIntersectingZone(location)
```

Comment: An alternate, if uncommon, syntax in SQL Server is: `No_of_Stations = count(*)`. [Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the Alias after the COUNT(*):

```
SELECT dbo.FindIntersectingZone(location) AS 'Zone', count(*) AS No_of_Stations
FROM londonStations
INNER JOIN [planning_districts_2008_updated]
  ON [planning_districts_2008_updated].geom.STIntersects(stations.location) = 1
GROUP BY dbo.FindIntersectingZone(location)
```

Comment: Worked. I knew it was something simple. Appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: I had to wait 10 minutes to accept the answer... then I forgot. Sorry. Will do that now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To label a column in the query result set you want to use an Alias- easy enough to do by using the keyword `AS`